# How can I center this header menu beside the logo

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site that has a header that is meant to stretch across the whole page. In that header I want to include the logo and an un-ordered list as the navigation menu.

Last website I did, I had two images in the header so I used a class to center them. It looked like this

```
.centeredImage
{
text-align:center;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding:0px;
}
```

Here is an example of it in action
[Link](http://www.atstran.com)

But my list doesn't work as well with this. It puts the list on the next line underneath the logo.

Here is a JSFiddle of what is going on
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8FqyV/)

Can someone show me a simple way to correct this.

Comment: Where is the list supposed to go exactly?

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code, try to validate code e.g. with http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input before posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not wrap block type elements (like `ul`) inside an inline one (`p`) you can just delete it as it doesn't realy has any use.

Secondly, to get your aim, you can use the `display:inline-block` property so both elements are displayed on the same line and can be aligned with `text-align:center;`

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8FqyV/16/)**

HTML:

```
    <div id="header">
            <img src="images/companylogo.png" alt="Company Logo" height="150"/>
            <ul>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>About Us</li>
                <li>Galleries</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="container" class="container_12">
        <p>TagLine</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="slideShow" class="grid_12">
            <p>Slideshow</p>
        </div>
        <!--End slideShow-->
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="aboutUs" class="grid_4">
            <p>about us</p>
        </div>
        <div id="picture" class="grid_4">
            <p>Picture</p>
        </div>
        <div id="services" class="grid_4">
            <p>services</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="stuff" class="grid_4">
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div id="blog" class="grid_4">
            <p>blog</p>
        </div>
        <div id="form" class="grid_4">
            <p>form</p>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <!--End container_12-->
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

CSS :

```
#header {
    /*height:200px;*/
    background-color:rgb(87, 140, 43);
    width:100%;
}
#header {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:100%;
}
#header img, #header ul{
    display:inline-block;
}
#footer {
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    width:100%;
}
#slideShow {
    height:200px;
    background-color:green;
}
#aboutUs {
    background-color:green;
    height:165px;
}
#services {
    background-color:green;
    height:165px;
}
#picture {
    background-color:orange;
    height:165px;
}
#stuff {
    background-color:orange;
    height:165px;
}
#blog {
    background-color:green;
    height:165px;
}
#form {
    background-color:orange;
    height:165px;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. Will accept as answer in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` instead of `p`

```
<div class="centeredImage">
    <img src="images/companylogo.png" alt="Company Logo" height="150">
    <ul>
        <li>Services</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Galleries</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FqyV/20/)

Comment: That centers the list like I want. But not the logo. I would like both to be centered and next to each other. I'm using the 960 grid system for the body so my fiddle isn't working correctly. But I want the logo and menu to be centered so it will fit into the 960 pixel range.

Answer (score 0):

Use `div` instead of `p` and make `list-style: none`

```
.centeredImage ul li{
    list-style: none;
}
```

Look at this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8FqyV/17/)